# accessing session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have stored a session using the following in one of my .php file:

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['uid'];
```

When I navigate to some other .php file and tried to access the value by doing:

```
$_SESSION['uid']
```

I got an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\saved.php on line 6
```

line 6 is:

```
$result->execute(array($_SESSION['uid']));
```

Why is this?

Comment: Have you called `session_start();` in your other scripts?

Comment: have you tried session_start() before calling $_SESSION?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you call `session_start()` on every page on which you want to access session vars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute `session_start();` on every page where you want to use `$_SESSION`. Otherwise PHP does not load the session.

Answer (score 1):

you must call `session_start();` in the other script as well.